# Hide div when you can't scroll the page and show div when there is a scroll bar and you need to scroll the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, hide

i want to hide a div when the page fills the screen and there is no need for a scroll bar. 
But when the page is large and the screen is small and the user needs to scroll down to see all of the page i want to show the div.

Hope you understand my needs, thank you for your help.

---

*edit (this one not seems to work what am i doing wrong)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if($(document).height() > $(window).height()){
$("#scrollTop").show();
}
else {
$("#scrollTop").hide();
}
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814398/jquery-check-if-scrollbar-visible-div-with-overflowauto

Did you check?

Comment: Since your're depending on the document being loaded, try wrapping your example script so [jQuery executes it when the document has loaded](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    if($(document).height() > $(window).height()){
        $(".yourDiv").show();
    }
    else {
        $(".yourDiv").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry this one don't work. see my edit of the post to see what i got right now.

Comment: Do you maybe also know a way how the div will come back if the screen expends and not longer fills the screen totally but there is a scroll bar needed after the expend of a screen? that would be realy fantastic :)