# How to detect whether a div is using scroll in bootstrap twitter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I check if a scrollbar is visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814398/how-can-i-check-if-a-scrollbar-is-visible)

I have a div with `overflow : auto` so i don't know when it scrolls. But it does depending upon the layout. Now i need to know when it is scrolling so that i can apply some business logic in it. How to capture this event?

Comment: You wanna know when the content exceeds the `height` and `width`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this way. You need to attach a handler when the content changes. And check if the content `width`, `height` and `scrollWidth`, `scrollHeight` are equal.

You can do with **jQuery**, this way:

```
if ($("div").scrollHeight == $("div").height)
   // Has Scrollbars
```