# Php page jumps right when navigating from page to page

Tags: php, html

Building a basic Php web site and my "Events" and "Join" pages jump slightly to the right when  moving from page to page. I know this is something really simple, yet I can not remember, nor figure out what I have done wrong. Any help sincerely appreciated.

(link has been removed because this question has been answered)

Comment: isn't it because if you are navigating from home you have scroll bars and in Events/Join Page there's none to it moves like that?

Comment: I think this has to do with the size of your browser window - there's nothing wrong with your page. It's "jumping to the right" because the page is so short (vertically) that it doesn't need a scrollbar.  (It's the scrollbar going away that causes the jump.) Once you put more stuff on that page, it won't really be a problem (for most viewers on most devices...)

Comment: Thank you very much!  I thought I was losing my mind... :)

Comment: This really isn't a programming question at all, and now has the original page link removed such that there is basically no value in retaining this question in the system.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a rather interesting exercise. For most circumstances, the comments provided by @Vainglory07 and @Kristen are correct: just live with the fact that scrollbars are going to make a centered page jump slightly between pages. In the common case that most of what you're doing is in some sort of container HTML tag there are ways of manipulating the location of the container to keep it from moving when a scrollbar appears. In case this bothers you (it looks you went with just making the container sufficiently long that a vertical scrollbar does appear), there are two possible solutions I can think of.

- (Easy, but forces you to make design tradeoffs) Design your page around CSS that specifies the `left` attribute of some container tag, e.g. either some container `div` or the `body` tag, which people often forget is perfectly fine as a container by itself. This precludes you from centering the container or otherwise moving it around.
- (Harder, but gives you the ability to center) Many times we would prefer for our container to be centered rather than aligned from the left. @Reigel gives a nice example of using Javascript to detect whether a scrollbar is present at [How can I check if a scrollbar is visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814398/how-can-i-check-if-a-scrollbar-is-visible). Using the same idea we can keep our container from moving from the user's point of view when a scrollbar pops up.

Note that the second solution will cause problems if you're trying to follow responsive CSS paradigms. The second solution is also fairly brittle. Resizing the page will mean the calculations for figuring out how much space to add to a side of the container get thrown off and the page will have to be reloaded. Moreover, this is overkill for most (almost all) circumstances; often it's easier to just ignore the "jump" that occurs when a scrollbar appears. You get used to it after a while. So the general solution is **just live with it**. For those people who obsess over that "jump" though, there's at least a partial solution for you guys.