# Maintain the same layout position with and without scrollbar at Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a request from the customer that the menu items position must not change when the page get taller and the scrollbar appears.

If the scrollbar appears, the width of the page get smaller and this is why the centered menu position shifts to the left. How can I preoccupy the scrollbar width so the layout stays the same when it first appears?

To see a live example of this effect

- please visit http://getbootstrap.com/,
- increase the height of the window that much that the scrollbar disappears and
- navigate to an other page using the menu (such as http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)

You will notice that the menu items are shifting a bit to the left. How I may hide this effect?

Comment: see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814398/how-can-i-check-if-a-scrollbar-is-visible And if scrollbar is visible adjust the navigation container accordingly. If you share code I can help you better

Comment: @Gokhan just grab any Example from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples. So are you saying that only with javascript I could make this work? Isn't there any solution with css?