# CSS overflow: scroll; --scrollbar is only visible on hover / scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar, overflow

I know this sounds like a super redundant question, but its not. Whenever I search for this I only get results telling me to use overflow:scroll -which I am.

I've tried this in chrome, chrome canary, safari, and firefox. I have a div with fixed height and width, some pages require scrolling others do not so I am using overflow: scroll; but the scroll bars only show when you actually scroll down while hovering over the content. I want it to be painfully obvious to my visitors that there is more content. Is there a way to have the scrollbars literally always show (whether or not the user is hovering or scrolling at that moment).

A JS solution would be cool, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814398/how-can-i-check-if-a-scrollbar-is-visible) has a neat trick to tell if the scrollbar is needed, but is there a JS function that always shows it? Is there a CSS function, pretty much anything would be cool.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: After playing around with JS I found that if you use

```
content.scrollTop = 0;
```

some browsers will flash the scrollbar, and for the other browsers use:

```
content.scrollTop = 1;
content.scrollTop = 0;
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

Instead of

```
overflow:scroll;
```

try

```
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:scroll;
```