# Scroll issue using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I get an issue using `scrollLeft` in jQuery, I'd like to scroll a fixed header in same times to the body element but the header is longer than the body so there is an issue at the end of the scroll with the width property...

JSFiffle : [JSFiddle using SCSS and jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/tonymx227/gj7ejp10/)

My

```js
( function($){
  $(document).ready( function(){
    function resizeHeader(){
      var fixedCell = document.querySelector('.grid4 .fixed').children;
      for( var i = 0; i < fixedCell.length; i++ ){
        var newWidth = fixedCell[i].offsetWidth;
        document.querySelector('.grid4 .cloned').children[i].style.width = newWidth;
      }
    }
    resizeHeader();
    $('.grid4 .scroll').scroll( function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      $('.grid4 .cloned').animate({
        scrollLeft: $this.scrollLeft()
      },0);
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.grid4{

  .grid{
    position: relative;

    .wrap{
      position: absolute;
      top: 20px;
      left: 0;
      height: 200px;
      width: 150px;

      .scroll{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        overflow-x: auto;

        .table{
          display: table;
          table-layout: fixed;
          margin: -20px 0 0 0;

          .header{
            display: table-header-group;
            background-color: green;

            .row{
              display: table-row;

              .cell{
                display: table-cell;
              }
            }

            .cloned{
              position: absolute;
              left: 0;
              top: -20px;
              background-color: red;
              display: table-row;
              width: 150px;
              overflow-x: hidden;
            }
          }

          .body{
            display: table-row-group;
            background-color: red;

            .row{
              display: table-row;

              .cell{
                display: table-cell;
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
        <div class="grid4">
          <div class="grid">
            <div class="wrap">
              <div class="scroll">
                <div class="table">
                  <div class="header">
                    <div class="row fixed">
                      <div class="cell" style="width: 100px;">Colonne</div>
                      <div class="cell">Colonne</div>
                      <div class="cell">Colonne</div>
                      <div class="cell">Colonne</div>
                      <div class="cell">Colonne</div>
                      <div class="cell">Colonne</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row cloned">
                      <div class="cell">Colonne</div>
                      <div class="cell">Colonne</div>
                      <div class="cell">Colonne</div>
                      <div class="cell">Colonne</div>
                      <div class="cell">Colonne</div>
                      <div class="cell">Colonne</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="body">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #1</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #2</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #2</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #2</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #2</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #2</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #2</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #3</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #3</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #3</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #3</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #3</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #3</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                      <div class="cell">Ligne #4</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

code :

Comment: You should provide your code outside of the JSFiddle aswell

Comment: they are the same size, just the body has a scrollbar (which is inline) causes to look smaller. you should check if the scrollbar for the body is visible and then adjust your header's width accordingly.

Comment: Ok and is there any solutions to stop the scroll ?

Comment: stop the scroll? no, I don't think you would want it. you just need to check if the scrollbar is visible on the body. and if it's visible, then lower the width of your head. you are done.

Comment: You can take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814398/how-can-i-check-if-a-scrollbar-is-visible

Comment: Umm this is not the issue, the problem is that there is a gap at the end of the scroll... Take a look on the JSFiddle and look at slowly at the end... The header is moved to the left like 10px to the left...

Comment: Right and what he is saying is the reason is because the slider knows it can go farther because the header is technically not on the screen (past the vertical scroll bar) and thus it lets you move over more and thus pushing your rows to the left.

Comment: Yes and this is the issue...

Comment: Can you accept the answer so others know this is resolved.  @tonymx227

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*** UPDATED ***
Ok so leave the header where it is, but add `overflow:hidden` as suggested in the comments

```
.cloned{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -20px;
    background-color: red;
    display: table-row;
    width: 133px; // Should be 133px not 132px
    overflow: hidden; // ADD
 }
```

Working JSFiddle for what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/gj7ejp10/7/

Comment: That is adding the scroll bar now.  Which is what the user in the comment had suggested.

Comment: Ok so that's better, but is there any solutions to hide the scrollbar in the header?

Comment: That is what I was looking for, duh didn't change width. :)

Comment: added fix, thank you @VitorinoFernandes  Width was a bit off, but fixed that

Comment: Why 132px for .cloned? If the scrollbar width is equal to more than 30px...?

Comment: Scroll bar width is not 30 pixels, not quite sure what you mean, the top is back to -20px and and wrap top to 20px but that has nothing to do with the Scroll bars width.  Look at my JSFiddle.

Comment: Scroll bar (referring to the right slider bar, not the whole row) is 17px in width, thus 133px instead of 150px.