# How to differentiate two divs with and without scroll bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with css

```
.comment-list {
margin: 20px 0;
max-height: 100px;
min-height: 100px;
overflow-y: scroll;
width: 100%;
background-color:#000;
}
```

and HTML

```
<div class="comment-list"> </div>
```

if it's too high scroll y become appear and no content no scroll bar...how can determine scroll bar is present or not using Jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/0p0k3f2h/

in the above link i was used the same div with and without content

Comment: Please post all the relevant code within the question. Your question by itself makes little sense without the HTML from your JSFiddle snippet, and if JSFiddle goes down for whatever reason this question will be unsalvageable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check if a scrollbar is visible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814398/how-can-i-check-if-a-scrollbar-is-visible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question : *how can determine scroll bar is present or not using Jquery?*

You can check for the `height()` with `scrollHeight`:

```js
$('.comment-list').each(function(i){
   if ($(this).height() < $(this).get(0).scrollHeight){
      $(this).prepend('has Scrollbar').css('color', 'white');
   }
});
```

```css
.comment-list {
    margin: 20px 0;
    max-height: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment-list"> </div>
      
<div class="comment-list">
    foo<br/>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>
    foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Whoa! No reasons for downvote as this code is working.

Answer (score 0):

I did't completely get your question but if you are trying to make the scroll bar disappear if it is not required try this http://jsfiddle.net/0p0k3f2h/2/.

Use `overflow:auto;`

```
.comment-list {
margin: 20px 0;
max-height: 100px;
min-height: 100px;
overflow-y: auto;
width: 100%;
background-color:#000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery "scroll" function you can easily identify.

```
 $( ".comment-list" ).scroll(function() {
    // scrollbar appeared
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if there is a scroll bar or not, use javascript (or jquery if you prefer) to get the hight of an inner element, if its over you parent elements max-height, then there should be a scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `overflow-y: scroll;` to `overflow-y: auto;` to do that:

```
.comment-list {
margin: 20px 0;
max-height: 100px;
min-height: 100px;
overflow-y: auto;
width: 100%;
background-color:#000;
}
```

Here's **[the updated working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0p0k3f2h/3/)**.

And if the div contains much text that needs scroll it will be there, else it will not be shown.

Comment: if I've read it right the OP wants to use javascript to check IF a scrollbar is visible or not (due to content inside), rather then use css to show/hide the scrollbar

Comment: Yes, but if CSS gives the wanted result why whould we use Javascript???

Comment: css can't tell you if a scrollbar is visible. I.e. if the user wanted to 'do' something IF the div had a scrollbar (maybe content is dynamic from the server), then javascript would be required. But again I mayhave missunderstood the OP, 'differentiate' to me suggests somesort of check rather then a style rule

Comment: "how can determine scroll bar is present or not using Jquery" - OP

Comment: But why do we need to determine if the scroll bar is present or not  if CSS can do all the job for us? I'm quite sure that the OP wants to make this scroll bar show automatically whenever it's needed.

Comment: just quoting from the question "how can determine scroll bar is present or not using Jquery", you'd have to ask the OP as to why he wants to do it

Comment: @atmd Yes indeed, I saw it and Thanks too for pointing it out, but I'm sure that logically that's what the OP wants to achieve.

Comment: Thanx everybody I got what I needed