# Auto-detect when scrollbar disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I got a centered Layout including a `max-width` and `margin: 0 auto;`. Furthermore i am currently using `Isotope` for filtering and sorting a grid.

*The Problem is:* There is the possibility that the height of the body / main container becomes smaller than the actual window height and therefor of course removes the scrollbar, since the `body` has `overflow: hidden`. The centered layout jumps (because of the `margin: 0 auto`), which doesn't look very great.

*The Question:* Is there a **callback function** from Isotope where i could test if the scrollbar is shown or not? Or is there even a possibility to **bind** a function on the body when the scrollbar disappears? what is the best method to check if there is a scrollbar visible or not? (**EDIT//** as suggested an easy method is `$(document).height > $(window).height`, now i just need a triggered event to call the if statement)

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT** here is a [LINK TO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rvmzzo7o/) to play around

Comment: Why not just style it so the scrollbar is always present (just disabled when the window is smaller)? Problem avoided :)

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814398/how-can-i-check-if-a-scrollbar-is-visible

Comment: I'm not sure of a Isotope function to do this, but in plain JS if `document.height > window.height` then you have a vertical scrollbar.

Comment: na, doesn't fit into the design :P

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeah, but i would need an event to trigger that if statement!

Comment: `$(window).resize()`

Comment: unfortunately `window.resize` is not triggered when the scrollbar disappears..

Comment: I know, I mean you need to hook to window resize and check the doc.height against the window.height

Comment: I'd probably just check if the height of the page is bigger than the size of the window