# HTML + CSS only solution to detect scroll bars

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm trying to apply some styling rules to an element only if there is a scrollbar present. Is there a CSS-only solution to achieve this?

Comment: No, it is not possible by pure css, you have to use javacsript or jquery.

Comment: You can't do it solely by CSS. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4814526/1236613).

Comment: @alirezasafian That would be an answer.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've implemented a similar angular js solution but it is too much watchers for a simple feature so JS is not the option.

Comment: @GolezTrol I prefer to insert this kind of answer as comment.

Comment: Maybe, just *maybe*, you could do something with a preprocessor (e.g. SASS) in which you check whether a wrapper element is smaller than its children, in which case it would get a scrollbar, and then apply a style on that element. Though I'm not entirely sure you can.

Comment: @BramVanroy sass is a compile time processor. The scrollbar visibility is depended on screen size, content etc. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Partially true. If you are working with static widths, a preprocessor could work because all the info you need is there. But I suppose that you could hard-code it anyway then, so you're rght.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of HTML5 and CSS3 it is not possible to apply styles depending on the presence of the scroll bar only using those two technologies.