# Test scrollbar visible false positive

Tags: html, google-chrome, vue.js

I want to test if the document is **NOT** scrollable, by using

```
$el = document.documentElement
const noscroll = $el.clientHeight === $el.scrollHeight // false

console.log($el.clientHeight) // 977
console.log($el.scrollHeight) // 991
console.log($el.scrollTop) // 0
```

But there is no visible scroll bar in the window. Not sure why it's not working. I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42681820/5326588), but no luck.

Put in more context here:

```
this.getData().then(data => {
  this.$nextTick().then(() => {
    const $el = document.documentElement
    if (!this.isPageEnd && $el.clientHeight - $el.scrollTop === $el.scrollHeight) {
      this.getData()
    }
  })
 })
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the condition in the following line

`const noscroll = $el.clientHeight === $el.scrollHeight`  << --  this line will only return true if both the client height and scroll height are the same.

You need to check if  scroll height is less than or equal to client height

Sometimes   [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) might help

```js
$el = document.documentElement
const hasScroll = $el.scrollHeight <= $el.clientHeight

console.log($el.clientHeight)
console.log($el.scrollHeight)
console.log(hasScroll)
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 1200px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>A large div</p>

</div>
```

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. Actually I only want to test if it has NO scroll. The test returns false whereas I cannot see visible scrollbar in the page. Isn't it false positive?

Comment: Updated my question with NOT :)

Comment: Updated the answer with `<=`  condition. If `scrollHeight` is less than  or equals to `clientHeight` then scroll bar is not visible

Comment: Updated my question with more context